# Set class in HTML table, but not for the entire column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is the situation, I have a `HTML` file with a table, the table gets filled with `XML` data. The last column (10) got a number in it: 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5. I've got 5 lines of `jQuery` which look for the number and give the cell with the corresponding number a specific class, this works fine (The cell has 0% opacity because it's not meant to be "shown", but for our means, it works fine like that).

Now the problem is: Column 7 and 8 need to get that class to without the whole column getting it, just the row with the specific number.

I've got a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Twanekkel/8sL86sc7/) so you can see the code and stuff:

The jQuery:

```
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('1')").addClass('disaster');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('2')").addClass('high');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('3')").addClass('average');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('4')").addClass('warning');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('5')").addClass('information');
```

**Note**: The data in the table is just for testing, the real xml will have those number of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in like 100 rows in a random order.

**EDIT:** Got a picture of how it should look: [image]

```js
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('1')").addClass('disaster');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('2')").addClass('high');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('3')").addClass('average');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('4')").addClass('warning');
$("td:nth-child(10):contains('5')").addClass('information');
```

```css
td:nth-child(10) { 
opacity: 0;
}
.disaster{ 
background-color: #E45858
}
.high{ 
background-color: #E87658
}
.average{ 
background-color: #FEA058
}
.warning{ 
background-color: #FEC858
}
.information{
background-color: #7498FE
}
/*CSS for main elements*/
div { 
max-width: 2600px;
display: block;
}
body {  
font-family: Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
table {  
text-align: left;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
th { 
font-size: 75%; 
font-weight: normal;
color:  #768C98;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #DCE2E4;
}
td { 
font-size: 75%; 
color: #1F2C33;
height: 25px;
padding-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
} 
img { 
position: absolute; left: -100px;
margin-top: 165px;
transform: rotate(270deg);
}
/*CSS for Hover*/
td:nth-child(1):hover{ 
text-decoration: underline;
}
td:nth-child(1) { 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
td:nth-child(2) { 
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr.NoHover:hover{  
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
tr:hover {  
background-color: #E8F5FF;
}
/*Column specific CSS*/
th.col1 { 
text-align: right;
width: 240px;
padding-right: 18px
}
th.col2 { 
width: 11px;
padding: none; 
}
th.col3 { 
text-align: left;
width: 188px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
th.col4 { 
text-align: left;
width: 70px;
}
th.col5 { 
text-align: left;
width: 77px;
padding-left: 82px;
}
th.col6 { 
text-align: left;
width: 430px;
}
th.col7 { 
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 497px;
}
th.col8 { 
text-align: left;
width: 498px;
}
th.col9 { 
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px;
width: 75px;
}
td:nth-child(1) { 
text-align: right;
color: #0274B8;
padding-right: 18px;
border-right: 2px solid #AAD6F0;
border-bottom: none;
}
td:nth-child(2) { 
color: white;
border-bottom: none;
width: 11px;
padding: none;
}
td:nth-child(3) { 
text-align: left;
text-decoration: underline dotted; 
padding-left: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(4) { 
text-align: left;
color: #DC0000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(5) { 
text-align: right;
text-decoration: underline dotted;
padding-right: 15px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(6) { 
text-align: left;
text-decoration: underline dotted;  
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;      
}
td:nth-child(7) { 
text-align: left;
text-decoration: underline dotted ;
padding-left: 10px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(8) { 
text-align: left;
text-decoration: underline dotted;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
td:nth-child(9) { 
text-align: left;
padding-left: 10px; 
border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEEF0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<br><br>
<div id="main">
 <table id="Table">
  <thead>
   <tr class="NoHover">
    <th class="col1" scope='col' >Time&#9660;</th>
    <th class="col2" scope='col' ></th>
    <th class="col3" scope='col' >Client</th>
    <th class="col4" scope='col' >Status</th>
    <th class="col5" scope='col' >Site</th>
    <th class="col6" scope='col' >Host</th>
    <th class="col7" scope='col' >Problem &bull; Cause</th>
    <th class="col8" scope='col' ></th>
    <th class="col9" scope='col' >Frequency</th>
    <th class="col10" scope='col'></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody id="TableData"> 
   <tr>
    <td>2017-11-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Client 1</td>
    <td>FAILING</td>
    <td>Site 1</td>
    <td>PC1</td>
    <td>test1</td>
    <td>Unable to open service</td>
    <td>24x7</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017-11-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Client 2</td>
    <td>FAILING</td>
    <td>Site 2</td>
    <td>PC2</td>
    <td>test2</td>
    <td>Unable to open service</td>
    <td>24x7</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017-11-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Client 3</td>
    <td>FAILING</td>
    <td>Site 3</td>
    <td>PC3</td>
    <td>test3</td>
    <td>Unable to open service</td>
    <td>24x7</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017-11-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Client 4</td>
    <td>FAILING</td>
    <td>Site 4</td>
    <td>PC4</td>
    <td>test4</td>
    <td>Unable to open service</td>
    <td>24x7</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2017-11-22</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Client 5</td>
    <td>FAILING</td>
    <td>Site 5</td>
    <td>PC5</td>
    <td>test5</td>
    <td>Unable to open service</td>
    <td>24x7</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the desired result? For one, I can tell you that `:nth-child(10)` doesn't seem to select anything, so there's clearly something wrong there, but I don't exactly understand what you want to accomplish. An image with the desired result could help!

Comment: :nth-child(10) has an opacity of 0% so it will not be shown, give me a few minutes I will make an image

Comment: Do you mean something like this [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/fhaskv5t/) Ah, I have just noticed you only want them in selected columns. I'm sure you could add a class to those and target them that way.

Comment: Changing the opacity shows that it works as expected - [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8sL86sc7/1/).

Comment: @AngelosChalaris Here's the image: https://imgur.com/gallery/0qp4Y

Comment: @NewToJS You got damn close, Adding a class should be posible yes, I will try

Comment: Can you edit your Original Question to add the image and other relavant information? Also consider to add a runable snippet instead of relying on a jsfiddle.

Comment: @user3154108 How does one add a runable snippet? Or do you mean just copy all the code in the question? The question has been solved so should I still edit it?

Comment: @Twanekkel next to the insert image icon in the toolbar is a `Javascript/HTML/CSS Snippet` Icon. You can then paste your code in the uppopping Interface. And yes, I would recommend the edit even after it has been solved. The idea is that other people with a similar question can find yours and find it usefull. When your Jsfiddle is deleted your question will be pretty worthless to others ;)

Comment: @user3154108 Did it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `.siblings()` selector:

```
    $("td:nth-child(10):contains('1')").siblings('td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8)').addClass('disaster');
    $("td:nth-child(10):contains('2')").siblings('td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8)').addClass('high');
    $("td:nth-child(10):contains('3')").siblings('td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8)').addClass('average');
    $("td:nth-child(10):contains('4')").siblings('td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8)').addClass('warning');
    $("td:nth-child(10):contains('5')").siblings('td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8)').addClass('information');
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8sL86sc7/2/

Comment: Yaaas, Thank you! :)

Answer (score 5):

Something like this maybe? ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fhaskv5t/1/))

```
$("tr").each(function(index) {
    var row = $(this),
    lastCol = row.find('td:nth-child(10)'),
    appendTo = row.find('td:nth-child(7), td:nth-child(8), td:nth-child(10)');
    switch(lastCol.text()) {
        case '1':
        appendTo.addClass('disaster');
        break;
        case '2':
        appendTo.addClass('high');
        break;
        case '3':
        appendTo.addClass('average');
        break;
        case '4':
        appendTo.addClass('warning');
        break;
        case '5':
        appendTo.addClass('information');
        break;
    }
});
```

If there are a lot of rows and you don't need extra stuff to happen exept for the added classes, this could be overkill. the `.siblings()` selector (as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47570407/1397220)) could be enough.

Comment: Got it working by McVenco, but tested yours as well and it worked just fine. his only was a bit easyer and I can't acceps 2 awnsers, still thanks a lot!!

Comment: Sometimes I forget there are simple solutions out there ;)